# Set default file permission mode without ACLs

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions, amazon-efs

I have an AWS EFS share, which does not support filesystem ACLs. How can I set a folder inside the EFS share to default to mode `664`?

Answer (score 1):

with `umask`:

```
umask 002 /the/directory
```

That will set the directory itself and the directories inside to have `775` permissions and the files to have `664` permissions.

The directory (and subdirectories) will have execute permissions for owner, group, and others in order to allow them to be traversed. The files will have read-write for the owner, read-write for the group, and read for others.

As mentioned below, this also depends on the processes writing to the directory. Other users with modify access can also change the umask itself or for the subdirectories inside if any exist.

Comment: Please note that `umask` is a per-process setting - you need to take that into account if multiple processes are used to create files into the directory.

Comment: @shodanshok I've added that and something else to the answer.